# Use custom styles in sidebar

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

Can I use custom styles for the Google Sheets Sidebar? Or will this not pass the addon review for the marketplace publishing?

I know there is stated

> Use the add-ons CSS package in your HTML service pages

But I would like to use UI5 framework that comes with its own styles. And I don't want to create completely new theme for UI5 just because of this.

Comment: Many add-on developers have used other CSS packages.  The Google add-ons CSS package doesn't have a lot in it.  I don't use UI5, but I do use a combination of the add-ons CSS and another CSS package.  The way that I do that is by putting the CSS into an html file and using templated HTML, rather than loading it in a link tag.  Then I removed the button and text styling from the other CSS package, so that it doesn't interfere with the add-on CSS button and text styling.  So, basically I'm using the other CSS package for layout, color, and anything that the add-on package doesn't have.

Comment: IMHO, while it's a very interesting question, it looks like a primarily opinion-based question because as you already mentioned the official docs haven't clear guidelines about the use of custom CSS. I suggest you to try the Google Apps Script Community https://developers.google.com/apps-script/community